# Why is little to no current flowing through this resistance?

Tags: circuit-analysis

This a multisim reimplementation [image]

of this original schematic-circuit: [image]

Why is the flow of current in the bottom resistor that low??

Comment: In the original circuit, the bottom resistor is 4 Ohms, but in the Multisim circuit it is 1000 Ohms.

Comment: @PeterBennett fixed it, still the same behavior, very low current

Comment: Try to remove 4 Ohm resistor from the circuit.  Next, try to find the voltage difference between the left and the right voltage dividers.

Comment: @G36 so after removing that resistor, the low bottom voltage from the left most end to the right most end is 154.2 micro Volts

Comment: That's odd, it should be 0 volts because the voltage dividers are equivalent. Perhaps something wrong with how the sim was set up?

Comment: The left voltage divider voltage is  \$V_L = 8V * \frac{2Ω}{3Ω + 2Ω} = 3.2V\$ and the right voltage divider voltage is \$V_R = 8V * \frac{4Ω}{6Ω + 4Ω}= 3.2V\$. So the voltage difference seen by the 4Ω resistor is 0V. Thus, no current will flow through it. What you see is a simulation artifact I guess.

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/yl9vnc8j

Comment: @G36 great transformation i didnt know how you could still preserve the same behavior by placing the lower resistor in between the two meshes is there any intuition / logic behind it?

Comment: https://postimg.cc/HcfD6pjz is this a valid equivalent circuit? if so how do i measure the voltage divider potential? if it isnt what should i fix? @G36

Comment: not equivalent ... the 6, 4 and 4 are not in the circuit

Comment: @jsotola oh really how'd you know?

Comment: the 2 and 3 are connected together directly ... the rest of the resistors are connected at only one node, so they have no current flowing through them

Comment: The authors deliberately drew this diagram in such a convoluted way, in order to not make it easier for beginners.  As for the intuition on how to redraw it.  All you need is some imagination and a lot of practice. Look here https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjRsC.png  I hope that now you can see that we have exactly the same circuit just drawn in a different way.

Comment: but is V_x = -4.8 V or +4.8 V? @G36 I would say it is -4.8 V due to how its polarized

Comment: Yes, the Vx voltage is -4.8V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the flow of current in the bottom resistor that low??

Because the potential (voltage) on one side of the resistor is approximately the same as the potential on the other. That is there is no potential difference.

If the resistances in the circuit were perfect, there would be exactly 0 potential difference.

The left hand resistors form a voltage divider, whose output is 8*(2/5) = 3.2 V relative to the battery's negative terminal.

The right hand resistors for another voltage divider, whose output is 8*(4/10) = 3.2 V relative to the battery's negative terminal.

Comment: ah yes exactly, same for the upper resistors they have the same potential